# How can I use OWL Import with relative paths?

Tags: rdf, owl

In my OWL file, I import many other files like:

```
<owl:imports rdf:resource="file:/home/noor/Downloads/bbc/Anatidae.rdf"/>
<owl:imports rdf:resource="file:/home/noor/Downloads/bbc/Animal.rdf"/>
<owl:imports rdf:resource="file:/home/noor/Downloads/bbc/Bird.rdf"/>
<owl:imports rdf:resource="file:/home/noor/Downloads/bbc/Chordate.rdf"/>
<owl:imports rdf:resource="file:/home/noor/Downloads/bbc/kingdom.rdf"/>
<owl:imports rdf:resource="file:/home/noor/Downloads/bbc/Mammal.rdf"/>
```

But I'm not able to manage relative paths; all these are failing:

```
<owl:imports rdf:resource="file:Anatidae.rdf"/>
<owl:imports rdf:resource="file:./Anatidae.rdf"/>
```

How can I do this with relative paths?

Answer (score 4):

Imports are supposed to point to URIs rather than local files, therefore some tools do not support yet the import from local assets. In order to handle local files, you have the following solutions:

- A quick fix would be to expose your RDF via a local web server and access them like this (e.g. `<owl:imports rdf:resource="http://localhost/Chordate.rdf"/>`).
- If you are using Protege to open your OWL file, you can configure the mapping between the actual files and the import IRI in the `Active Ontology` --> `Import ontology` tab.
- Last solution, if you work with [Brain](http://loopasam.github.io/Brain/) you can easily load the files one by one without dealing with the `owl:imports`, example:

  `Brain brain = new Brain();`

  `brain.learn("/home/noor/Downloads/bbc/Bird.rdf");`